# Is putting an empty string in .outerHTML equivalent to remove()?

Tags: javascript

So if I have a `<span class="iii"></span>` container... and I use you know:

`document.querySelector('.iii').outerHTML='';` it removes the span and essentially removes that span element from the DOM and everything inside of it correct?  Is it really, technically deleting/removing it from the DOM? Does it perform what remove() does?

I ask this, because .remove() is a new experimental method that is not cross browser correct? I'm trying to find a cross browser way to 'remove an element', and `outerHTML = '';` does that for me, but I am asking this question because it doesn't seem **right**. outerHTML's function isn't for deleting, (or can it be) or is it? 
Edit: added `.iii` my bad.

Comment: el.parentNode.removeChild(el)

Comment: Thank you Plalx, what is the difference between that method and `outerHTML='';` , (When using `outerHTML='';`) they are both 'deleting' or 'removing' my element when used? If you will, I believe your method is more appropriate, right?

Comment: MSDN says that `outerHTML` is read-only for some types of elements.

Comment: removeChild is a function, outerHTML is a variable setter for a string

Comment: @andygoestohollywood yeah, but it's essentially doing the same thing at the end of the day when I use `outerHTML='';`, the element gets removed... I still don't understand why it removes the element, shouldn't it just not touch the element, if it's setting the outer HTML to nothing? To what? why does the element even get touched, shouldn't it only be set to something if something exists inside the `''`'s?

Comment: @NiCkNewman not really it's not actually 'removing' the element it's simply setting the HTML around it to nothing, then when the browser updates it's representation of the DOM it realizes that the element is now gone and removes it from the DOM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any significant difference between them when it comes to removing elements from the DOM. For your case they both remove the element, and that's the end of the story.

Here are the most obvious differences that come to mind (*feel free to add any other ones*):

### `outerHTML`

- It is a getter
- It is a setter (*for the setter version it can be used to either "remove" or "replace" an element*)
- When you're either removing or replacing an element, you don't need to know its parent like you would need to with `el.parentNode.removeChild(el)`
- It works only with strings, which are then parsed into DOM objects
- It is a property and not a method
- It is supported by most Browsers

### `remove`

- It is a method
- It can remove Element and Text nodes where outerHTML isn't available on text nodes
- It can only work with DOM objects and not strings
- You don't need to know the element's parent, instead you just remove it
- It's not supported by most Browsers as it's new

Comment: `It's not supported by most Browsers as it's new.` It's been supported by every major browser except IE for over four years now, and IE has `el.removeNode(true)` which is functionally equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference, both will remove the element from the DOM removing all event handlers and other related properties from memory when the garbage collector decides to. As for performance I wrote a quick test, http://jsperf.com/outerhtmlblank-vs-remove and it turns out that `outerHTML = ''` is 14% faster on Google Chrome so I would say that is better to use. Feel free to test on other browsers to confirm the results.

When you call `outerHTML = ''` it sets the HTML around it to nothing, then when the browser updates it's representation of the DOM it realizes that the element is now gone and removes it from the DOM whereas remove() simply removes it from the DOM.

Comment: Oh wow, nice idea. I'm going to test Plalx's method removechild vs outerHTML as well.