# Getting unexpected error: Failed to set the 'outerHTML' property on 'Element': This element has no parent node

Tags: javascript

I have a function to play only the audio of a video mp4 file... part of the function is this (for simplicity I just write the error producing part):

```
const video = document.createElement('video');
document.body.appendChild(video);
video.id = 'audio-clip'; 
const clip = document.getElementById("audio-clip");
clip.style.visibility = "hidden";
const source = document.createElement('source');
source.src = getBlob(clipSource);
source.type = 'video/mp4';
video.appendChild(source);
video.load();
```

Then when I want to stop the video I simply remove it from the DOM by this function:

```
StopMovieAudio = () => {
   console.log('clip', clip);
   console.log('clip.outerHTML', clip.outerHTML);
   clip.outerHTML = "";
}
```

The issue is sometimes I get an error that ruins the whole code: here is my console:

[image]

As you see the weird part of the error is while I can log the `clip.outerHTML` and it returns the DOM correctly in the very next line I get the unexpected error:

> Failed to set the 'outerHTML' property on 'Element': This element has
> no parent node.

What have I missed and how to fix this?

**Edit:** Guys I noticed even more weird thing... the clip is not attached into body ... even though we can log `console.log('clip', clip);` and it returns the element, there is no such element in `console.log(document.body)`!!!!!!!

Comment: Maybe try `document.body.removeChild(clip)` instead of `clip.outerHTML = ""`

Comment: Try `clip.remove()`? BTW, your `video` and `clip` both refer to the same element.

Comment: "If the element has no parent element, setting its outerHTML property will not change it or its descendants. Many browsers will also throw an exception."
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML#Notes

Comment: Could it simply be that your function StopMovieAudio is called twice (or more)? The first time it removes 'clip' from the DOM, the second time it throws an error since 'clip' has no parent element any more.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28357126/is-putting-an-empty-string-in-outerhtml-equivalent-to-remove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using non-standard browser extensions such as outerHTML, but if you insist, outerHTML doesn't work on any elements that have been detached from the DOM that have no parent, or the HTML tag (which is expected to be the root).

I don't know how this applies to your situation at all, there's probably more code that you haven't shown.

Since you're seeking to remove the element, it would be more readable to use the W3C DOM API's `Node#remove`:

```js
clip.remove();
```

You can read more about it [at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove).

Comment: I accept your answer but the issue was something wired and I hope you can think about it and find an answer for it... I solved it by getting the element inside the `StopMovieAudio`  function I mean using `const clip = document.getElementById("audio-clip");` inside the function... I don't know how could it be possible that the `clip` which is getById outside of the function is different from the one I get inside the function...???

Comment: @SaraRee If you're not sure in the first place, why even do it at all? If anything, just check yourself: `console.log(video === clip);` But if you wanted them to be the same object, just rename one, and delete the `...getByID`. You cannot mess up something that you don't even *do*. Also, go ahead and check their `.parentElement` property too,

Comment: Where can I read about `outerHTML` being a "non-standard browser extension"?

Comment: `outerHTML` is standard.